# About CGRectFromString Use

Tags: iphone, position

In my apps, i want to use CGRectFromString to set UIButton position. my code just like that

```
NSString *g = @"{0,0},{100, 100}";
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(g);
self.button1.frame = rect;
```

but is dosent work. anything i miss or it's apple bug ??

Comment: have you tried the `CGRectMake(...)` function?

Comment: @holex Yes. i try it. it work. but CGRectFromString donent .. any idea for this ?

Comment: I fix that problem .. just NSString *g = @"{{0,0},{100,100}}";

Answer (score 5):

You can set frame using this , its working fine. follow this link to drop your eye on [CGRect](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/c/cgrect-cgsize-and-cgpoint.html)

```
CGRect optionsFrame = {{0, 0}, {100, 100}};
self.button1.frame = optionsFrame;
```

or if you really want to use `CGRectFromString` then please make soma changes

```
NSString *g = @"{{0,0},{100, 100}}";
```

I hope you understand..:)

Comment: Care to add some comment? How does it work, why you are propposing this solution?

Comment: This won't work, it's `CGRect optionsFrame = {{0, 0}, {100, 100}}`.

Comment: @Yaroslav its working fine for me., i tested all my code before give any solution.. and i am also using this code in my project

Comment: @Rajneesh071, it's not only about if it works or not, is about adding some comment so people will know what your code does and how it does it. This way it is more useful and understable

Comment: CGRect is not defined as `struct { CGFloat[4] points }`, but as `struct { CGPoint origin, CGSize size }`, so it's `{ {ox, oy}, {sw, sh} }`.

Comment: It works, because ultimately you'll have 4 CGFloats in your struct, but it's not written respectfully to the original typedef.

Comment: @Cyrille  - Thank you very much...now i understand the complete flow of CGRect

Comment: You're welcome. Removed my -1 as you've corrected your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this....

```
NSString *g = @"{{0,0},{100, 100}}";
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(g);
self.button1.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a bad idea, performance-wise. Using `CGRectFromNSString` the runtime needs to parse your string, which is costly. If this rect is really constant, you should use this single-liner:

```
CGRect optionsFrame = (CGRect){{0, 0}, {100, 100}};
```

The cast `(CGRect)` is here to prevent compiler complaints and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`CGRectMake`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake)?

```
self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
```

Comment: Thanks , but i have to use CGRectFromString for some reasone